# ionic require login on lazy loaded page for website

Tags: authentication, lazy-loading, ionic3

I have a simple Ionic3 app with a couple of lazy loaded pages (using `IonicPage`) and a login page. I want to block all access to any page unless the user is first logged in. Knowing that this is to build a website version and not a cordova version, what is the best way to prevent the user for simply typing in the url of the lazy loaded pages and access them without logging in? I'm guessing there must be some way to "tap" into the navigation and redirect to the login page from there but cannot find this anywhere in the documentation. Obviously I don't want to add the same code in every lazy-loaded page to do this.

Here is my idea on how this would work, keeping the logic of things where it should be:

```
// app.component.ts
import { UserAuthService } from '..';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(userAuth: UserAuthService) {
    userAuth.init(<whatever dependency needed>);
    userAuth.unauthorized().subscribe((auth: boolean) => {
      if (auth) {
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
      }
      else {
        this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
        this.nav.popToRoot();
      }
    });
  }
}

// user-auth.service.ts

export class UserAuthService {
  private auth: ReplaySubject;

  init(): {
    // code here to catch whatever page change there is, check if user is authorized and push new value
  }

  unauthorized(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.asObservable();
  }
}
```

And bonus point if I can return to the origin page after logging in successfully

Comment: _Obviously I don't want to add the same code in every lazy-loaded page to do this_: So using `NavGuards` is not an option?

Comment: @sebaferreras hum maybe, what is it?

Comment: I've undeleted my answer, let me know if that is not what you were looking for and I'll delete it again...

Comment: @sebaferreras oh yeah it is not what I want, for this you have to copy-paste the code in every page, or you need to create a master page that everyone else extends... this is what I do now, but this is not the `by-feature` way I'd need, where the "user feature" should control this

Comment: Since you already create a master page that everyone else extends, why don't you create another _master page_, `UserBasePage`, with the `ionViewCanEnter` hook there, and then extend that page in the _user only_ pages? This is what I do actually...

Comment: @sebaferreras because this is putting the logic of user auth in every page, which is not generic at all. If you do this for everything else, your code must be very hard to debug. I'll update my answer with some code to show the idea of how it should work

Answer (score 2):

After hours of working, finally i found a solution:
**Step1:** Defind a name for your `ion-nav` in app.html:

```
<ion-nav id="nav" #navCtrl [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

**Step2:** Get your `nav` by `Viewchild` in `app.component.ts`:

```
@ViewChild("navCtrl") nav: NavController;
```

**Step3:** Catch `ionViewDidEnter` of every page in `app.component.ts`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {  
    this.nav.viewDidEnter.subscribe(event=>{ 
      //If user is not logged in
      if(!this.checkUserLoggedIn()){
        if(event.name != "YourLoginPage")this.nav.setRoot("YourLoginPage");
      }
    })
}
checkUserLoggedIn(){
    //Your code to check whether user is logged in or not
}
```

Comment: Hmm, nice way to do it. I have two questions though: 1) Why do you use the `viewDidEnter` instead of something like `viewWillEnter`, so the user can not actually see the page? 2) Will this still work `event.name != "YourLoginPage"` if you use the `--prod` flag and the code gets minified and uglified by Webpack?

Comment: 1. `viewDidEnter` and  `viewWillEnter` is same in this case because we can not stop these lifecycles hook. If you use  `viewWillEnter`, it still fire  `viewDidEnter` before change page.

Comment: 2. I did not try in `--prod` mode, i am not sure lazy load page will change name after  minified and uglified or not. If it does not work, i believe that there is a walk around

Comment: @sebaferreras: tested with `--prod`. It works well :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments Duannx :)

Comment: Ah this is very close, but yeah the only problem is that the page still loads and then the `viewDidEnter` is triggered, so it's not a 100% solution but this is good. I will accept the answer if you can find a way to do 100% :D

Comment: @Guillaume: I know it is not perfect, but seem like we can not do better here.

Comment: now I have another problem: once the user logs in, how to return to the previous page... this whole thing is not really thought out on Ionic's team side

Comment: I think things might have changed in the last versions, because now on `3.9.2` I can no longer display the login page if the user tries to go to un unprotected page. I still don't have a solution to make my Ionic webapp secure!