# CSS styling is not working in production build Ionic

Tags: css, ionic2

I have created an application having side menu using ionic2. When I select an item from the side menu the item is highlighted like the below given picture.
[image]

the code for highlight is

```
isActive(page: any) {
let childNav = this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0];
if (childNav) {
  if (childNav.getSelected() && childNav.getSelected().root === page.tabComponent) {
    return 'danger';
  }
  return;
}

if (this.nav.getActive() && this.nav.getActive().name === page) {
  return 'danger';
}
return;
```

}

the html section is

```
<button ion-item menuClose  class="navigation-items" (click)="openPage('ChatPage')" detail-none>
          <ion-icon item-start name="chatbubbles" [color]="isActive('ChatPage')"></ion-icon>
          <span [ngClass]="isActive('ChatPage') ? 'red-color':'white-color'"> Chats</span>
        </button>
```

The issue comes when I create a production build using the command `ionic cordova run android --prod --release`
and signed using android studio. If I select the item from side menu it is not getting highlighted.

[image]

Could anyone please tell me why the css styling is not getting reflected in the production build?

Thanks and Regards
Dak

Comment: Explained in this video clearly - https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-menu-with-active-page-highlight-in-ionic-2/

Comment: @Cruzer Thank you very much. I changed my way according to that doc.
But still I didnt get why code is not working in production mode

Comment: @Dark are you using caching like local storage or something?

Comment: @Dak Do you use lazy load page?

Comment: @Cruzer No, I am not using

Comment: @Duannx Yes I am

Comment: @Dak: When you build with `--prod`, the page name will be changed. So you need to get it realtime. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499323/4254681) to know how to get it. When you have the correct page name, you will know which page is activating

Comment: @Duannx Could you please tell me why the page name is changed in production mode?

Comment: @Dak: The page name change when the code gets minified and uglified by Webpack. It is a process of ionic build `--prod`. I do not know the reason inside it but it actual changed.

Comment: @Duannx , If you add that as an answer, i can mark it. It will be useful for others

Comment: @Dak: It is just a suggestion.  Just use it to solve your problem and add the complete  answer. It would nice if you upvote my answer above. :D

Comment: @Duannx Done bro